# Vue - Share variable with slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Lets say I have made a button component with a variable `myVar`:

**MyButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :name="text">
      My Button
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-button',
  data() {
    return: {
      myVar: 'TEST'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And I want us this component in some other component:

**OtherComponent.vue**

```
<my-button>
  <div :slot="text">
    This is a Button
  </div>
</my-button>
```

How does one access the variable `myVar` declared in `MyButton.vue` inside the parent `OtherComponent.vue` slot definition? Example:

**OtherComponent.vue**

```
<my-button>
  <div :slot="text">
    This is myVar {{ myVar }} from MyButton.vue
  </div>
</my-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research I have found this:

**MyButton.vue**

```
<slot :name="text" slot-scope="slot" :myVar="myVar">
  My Button
</slot>
```

**OtherComponent.vue**

```
<my-button>
  <div :slot="text" slot-scope="slot">
    {{ slot.myVar }}
  </div>
</my-button>
```

See [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) for more info.